# Phaser animation help - chaining animations together

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to chain together animations using phaser.

When intro0 is finished, I need to play the animation defined in intro1.
However, the animation in intro 1 keeps looping. I need a way to stop the existing animation to start the new one.

If I use the  this.player.animations.stop in the intro1, all animations just stop. The idle animation does not run

Can anyone help?

```
intro0: function() {
  this.player.animations.play("run", 9, true);
  var s = this.game.add.tween(this.player);
  s.to({ y: 300,x:192 }, 3000, null)
  s.start();
  s.onComplete.add(this.intro1, this); //Which uses the Signals retains scope

},

intro1: function() {
  this.player.animations.play("idle", 9, false);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that: There is a sprite with an infinite animation but when the interpolation event ends the current animation ends and starts another animation, after finishing it then the sprite must be destroyed. If the new animation is another sprite I suppose you can use *loadTexture()*:

```
s.onComplete.add(function() { 
                    //The third parameter indicates whether to stop the current animation
                    player.loadTexture('texture', 0, true);
                    player.animations.add('idle'); 
                    //The fourth parameter indicates whether the sprite should be killed after the animation is finished
                    player.animations.play('idle', 9, false, true); 
                 }, this);
```

If you want to animate a certain number of frames you can do the following:

```
   player.animations.add('run', [0,1,2,3]);
   player.animations.add('idle', [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]);
   player.animations.play('run', 10, true);

   var s = game.add.tween(player);
   s.to({ y: 300,x:192 }, 3000, null);
   s.start();
   s.onComplete.add(function() { 
                       player.animations.stop(); 
                       player.animations.play('idle', 9, false, true); 
                    }, this);
```